# Cross Browser support Three Dimensional Model

Tags: html, svg, webgl, jquery-svg

I have to create a three dimensional model in a browser based application. This application should work on all major browsers.I want a technology other than java applet and flash.Can anyone please clarify my below questions?

1. What will be the best option to create a three dimensional model in a browser based environment ie WebGL or SVG?
2. Do we get any third party library for doing three dimensional applications in web browser?
3. I found that WebGL is supporting in Google chrome and Firefox. Then What will be the work around for supporting WebGL in other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's more likely to be a choice between WebGL and Canvas. Support for [Canvas](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas) is pretty much universal in all major MODERN browsers. [WebGL](http://caniuse.com/webgl) less so. In theory, the right library (see next) will allow you to choose the appropriate rendering context based on feature detection.
2. [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is probably your best bet and is more than capable of allowing you to import and manipulate your model.
3. See answer 1: either target Canvas directly or as the fall-back for a WebGL rendering context.

If you need to support IE 8 and below you will probably need to consider Flash as a fallback. three.js, as I understand it, is more or less a port of the popular Flash 3D engine [Papervision](http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/). I'm not sure the project is maintained anymore but, if you do require a Flash fallback, it might be worth considering because of the similarities in the API.